# Symbolic quadratic constrained maximization with non-negativity constraints?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Dear Mathematica users,

I attempted to maximize the below quadratic function `K`, subject to `x1+x2<=A`, and a series of non-negativity conditions.
Unfortunately, running the below syntax provides no solution as the kernel keeps running for hours without a result.

How can a symbolic solution for `x1` and `x2` be obtained?

Thank you for your help and I hope my question is clear.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
{xx = {x1, x2}, GG = {g1, g2}, BB = {1, 1}, QQ = {{q1, q12}, {q12, q2}}}
Alpha = (r/(A v))
K = GG.xx - (Alpha/2)  xx.QQ.xx
region = {BB.xx <= A, x1 >= 0 , x2 >= 0 , A >= 0, r >= 0, v >= 0, q1 >= 0, q2 >= 0}
Maximize[{K, region}, {x1, x2}]
```

Comment: Hi ! Why don't you try and maximize a simple function first, see if you are actually doing the right thing and then dive into the deep waters ? As a first step you are trying to re-define a built-in function (`K`), so you should change the name of your variable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does return a result:

```
pp1= Reduce[{D[K, x1] == 0     && D[K, x2] == 0 && 
             D[K, {x1, 2}] < 0 && D[K, {x2, 2}] < 0 && 
             D[K, {x2, 2}] D[K, {x1, 2}] > D[K, x1, x2]^2 &&
             And @@ region}, {x1, x2}, Reals]
```

`Solve[]` also works:

```
pp2 = Solve[{D[K, x1] == 0     && D[K, x2] == 0 && 
             D[K, {x1, 2}] < 0 && D[K, {x2, 2}] < 0 && 
             D[K, {x2, 2}] D[K, {x1, 2}] > D[K, x1, x2]^2 &&
             And @@ region}, {x1, x2}, Reals]
```

If the conditions for the existence of a maximum are met (they are convoluted and I haven't analyzed them), the coordinates are:

```
{x1, x2} /. pp2 /. ConditionalExpression[a_, b_] :> a // FullSimplify
(*
{{(A (g2 q12 - g1 q2) v) /((q12^2 - q1 q2) r), 
  (A (-g2 q1 + g1 q12) v)/((q12^2 - q1 q2) r)}}
*)
```

and the value of the maximum is

```
K /. pp2 /. ConditionalExpression[a_, b_] :> a // FullSimplify
(*
 {-((A (g2^2 q1 - 2 g1 g2 q12 + g1^2 q2) v)/(2 (q12^2 - q1 q2) r))}
*)
```

---

Example:

```
vals = {q1 -> 10, q2 -> 1, q12 -> -2, A -> 1, g1 -> 10, g2 -> -1, r -> 100, v -> 1};
Show[Plot3D[K /. vals, {x1, 0, .018}, {x2, 0, .018}], 
     Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Red, Point[{x1, x2, K} /. pp2 /. vals]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{x1, x2, K} /. pp2 /. vals
(*
{{1/75, 1/60, 7/120}}
*)
```